# Determining the McLaurin series of $(1-z)e^{-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Determine the Mclaurin series and the convergence radius for $(1-z)e^{-z}$.

I know the Taylor expansion of $e^t=\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}$.Replacing $t=-z$ then I have $e^{-z}=\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n z^n}{n!}$. Now the series would be: $(1-z)e^{-z}=(1-z)\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n z^n}{n!}=...$

The books solution is $1+\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1) z^n}{n!}$

I do not know how to manipulate the expression $(1-z)\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n z^n}{n!}$ in order to get the solution.

**Question**:

Can someone help me solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book's answer appears to be incorrect, or perhaps you've mistyped it.

It is perfectly accurate to say that $$(1-z)e^{-z}=(1-z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!},$$ but unfortunately, this isn't in the correct form, yet, since we need it to look like $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$ for some numbers $a_0,a_1,\dots.$ I'll walk you through how to get it there.

Note that for any $w\in\Bbb C,$ we have $(1-z)w=w-zw,$ so that $$(1-z)e^{-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}-z\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}\right),$$ or equivalently, $$(1-z)e^{-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}+(-1)z\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}\right).\tag{1}$$ Distributing the $(-1)z$ into the right-hand series in $(1),$ we obtain $$(1-z)e^{-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^{n+1}}{n!},\tag{2}$$ but now our powers of $z$ don't match! The right-hand series in $(2)$ is adding up $$\frac{(-1)^{0+1}z^{0+1}}{0!}+\frac{(-1)^{1+1}z^{1+1}}{1!}+\frac{(-1)^{2+1}z^{2+1}}{2!}+\frac{(-1)^{3+1}z^{3+1}}{3!}+\cdots,$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{(-1)^1z^1}{(1-1)!}+\frac{(-1)^2z^2}{(2-1)!}+\frac{(-1)^3z^3}{(3-1)!}+\frac{(-1)^4z^4}{(4-1)!}+\cdots,$$ so we can make the substitution $n\mapsto n-1$ in the right-hand series in $(2)$ to get $$(1-z)e^{-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{(n-1)!}.\tag{3}$$ Now the powers of $z$ in the two sums are matching, but the indices don't. However, we can simply take the $n=0$ term separately from the left-hand series in $(3),$ getting us $$(1-z)e^{-z}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{(n-1)!},$$ at which point we can combine the sums to get $$\begin{eqnarray}(1-z)e^{-z} &=& 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}+\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{(n-1)!}\right)\\ &=& 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}+\frac{(-1)^nnz^n}{n!}\right)\\ &=& 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)z^n}{n!}.\end{eqnarray}$$ This is probably what your book's answer is (supposed to be). We can do even better, though! Noting that each of $(-1)^0,$ $0!,$ $(0+1)$ and $z^0$ are equal to $1,$ we then have $$1=\frac{(-1)^0(0+1)z^0}{0!},$$ and so we have $$(1-z)e^{-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n!}z^n.$$

Can you show that this series converges everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not know how to get the sums together. Could you give me more hints please?

Comment: Can you tell how to rewrite $$z\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}\right)$$ in the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\textrm{stuff involving }z\textrm{ and }n,$$ at least?

Comment: Do you mean this $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{n+1}}{n!}\right)$?

Comment: Exactly! I have adjusted my answer to take you the rest of the way. Please let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You showed me a lot of techniques I was not aware of.

Comment: You're very welcome! Another way you could go is to simply consider the derivatives of the function $f(z)=(1-z)e^{-z}.$ Taking the first few derivatives, we see that $$f'(z)=-(2-z)e^{-z}\\f''(z)=(3-z)e^{-z}\\f'''(z)=-(4-z)e^{-z},$$ and so on. A quick proof by induction shows that the $n$th derivative is $$f^{(n)}(z)=(-1)^n(n+1-z)e^{-z}$$ for all $n$--including $n=0.$ Thus, $$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n(n-1)$$ for all $n,$ so that the $n$th coefficient of the Maclaurin series is $$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac{(-1)^n(n-1)}{n!}$$ for all $n.$

Comment: This is the most comprehensive，encyclopedic and thorough in-depth like an old grandpa teaching a child. If schools can exist such teachers there will be many mathematician even Gaussian type can be nurtured. I like it very much and worship your deeds!